# Объединение одинаковых значений в многомерном массиве

Tags: массивы, laravel

Есть массив вида

```
    array:211 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▼
    0 => "2Ц2-0"
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => "1"
    8 => null
    9 => null
    10 => null
    11 => null
    12 => null
    13 => null
    14 => null
    15 => null
    16 => null
    17 => null
  ]
  1 => array:18 [▼
    0 => "2Ц2-160Н"
    1 => "1"
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => null
    8 => null
    9 => null
    10 => null
    11 => null
    12 => null
    13 => null
    14 => null
    15 => null
    16 => null
    17 => null
  ]
  2 => array:18 [▼
    0 => "2Ц2-160Н"
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => "1"
    8 => null
    9 => null
    10 => null
    11 => null
    12 => null
    13 => null
    14 => null
    15 => null
    16 => null
    17 => null
  ]
]
```

Нужно пройтись по массиву и привести его к виду

```
    array:211 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▼
    0 => "2Ц2-0"
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => "1"
    8 => null
    9 => null
    10 => null
    11 => null
    12 => null
    13 => null
    14 => null
    15 => null
    16 => null
    17 => null
  ]
  1 => array:18 [▼
    0 => "2Ц2-160Н"
    1 => "1"
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => "1"
    8 => null
    9 => null
    10 => null
    11 => null
    12 => null
    13 => null
    14 => null
    15 => null
    16 => null
    17 => null
  ]
]
```

Comment: чтобы привести к тому же самому виду - ничего делать не надо :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там число элементов разное

Comment: @teran на самом деле там ещё кое-что есть. Но считаю, что автор должен как минимум внятно описать проблему......... а из текущего вообще можно ручками всё поправить

Comment: у меня в многомерном массиве имеются массивы с одинаковым названием 0 => "2Ц2-160Н", но с разными значениями от 1 до 17, и мне нужно объединить по ключу 0 так что бы например ключ 1 и ключ 7 были в 1м массиве и удалить дублированый

Comment: а если в обоих массивах есть один и тот же ключ?

Comment: если например по ключу 0 массивы одинаковые, то в первом массиве заполнить остальные значения из дубликатов, и дубликаты удалить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пройтись в циклах по массивам и объединить значения в новом.

```
$arr = [
    [
        0 => 'First',
        1 => null,
        2 => 'Value 1.2',
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Second',
        1 => 'Value 2.1',
        2 => null,
        3 => null,
    ],
    [
        0 => 'Second',
        1 => null,
        2 => 'Value 3.2',
        3 => 'Value 3.3',
    ],
];

$result = [];

foreach ( $arr as $subArr ) {
    $key = $subArr[0];

    if ( ! isset( $result[ $key ] ) ) {
        $result[ $key ] = $subArr;
        continue;
    }

    foreach ( $subArr as $k => $v ) {
        $result[ $key ][ $k ] = $v ?: $result[ $key ][ $k ];
    }
}
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [First] => Array
        (
            [0] => First
            [1] => 
            [2] => Value 1.2
        )

    [Second] => Array
        (
            [0] => Second
            [1] => Value 2.1
            [2] => Value 3.2
            [3] => Value 3.3
        )

)
```

Comment: Благодарю все работает